# Can we prioritise non-identify questions on the Twitter account?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, identify, bot

I follow the [Movies & TV SE Twitter account](https://twitter.com/stackmovies) and I've noticed that the vast majority of questions posted there are 'identify this movie' questions.

In particular, [this old question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/romantic-movie-about-two-people-who-speak-different-languages-falling-in-love) was just posted, but it's from 3 years ago and already has an accepted answer, so I don't see it at all useful to post.

I assume this is due to those questions getting more upvotes, and if they're getting more upvotes then I guess it's somewhat representative of what the users on this site like. (In which case, maybe the bigger question is why do people keep upvoting those questions?)

However, I feel like we should be showcasing a bigger variety of questions. Is it possible to reduce the priority of 'identify' questions on Twitter?

Comment: Don't know how the Twitter account works, but ID getting *more* upvotes? Sounds unlikely...

Comment: @Walt just [take a look](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) for yourself - 7/15 on the first page are upvoted, with 4 questions on 3+ votes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what this proves. Of the first 15 *non-ID* questions (excluding those 'on hold'), 10 are upvoted and 5 are 3+.

Comment: @Walt starting I only count 5/15 non-identify questions upvoted (starting from when you posted). But if there *are* more non-identify questions upvoted then clearly the Twitter bot is functioning incorrectly (or sub-optimally).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s no longer relevant